Using ACF Repeaters, that are using paralaxes
I have created a image and text block within ACF, and there are a bunch of options like switching sides of the text and image, can have a background etc.
The issue i am having, is that because you can duplicate these repeaters within wordpress on the pages, I have a parallax on the block, specifically the image block, and so, if you duplicate the repeater, the parallax obviously is duped also as the repeater is identical.
So when you scroll down, ALL the parallaxes will activate, which does not work as when you scroll down, the parallax blocks will be half way up the page as they are all starting at the same time.
Would there be a way to alter my code, so that the parallax only activates once it enters the viewport, rather than a scroll activation? Having the Paralax contained within it's own box.
I hope that makes sense
php:
<?php
if ($bgColour == 'yes') : ?>
<div class="bg-primary pseudo-100 py-5 z-n1">
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 <?= $directionTxt; ?> <?= $overTxt; ?>"><?= $text; ?>
        <?php
        $link = get_field('button');
        if ($link) :
            $link_url = $link['url'];
            $link_title = $link['title'];
            $link_target = $link['target'] ? $link['target'] : '_self';
        ?>
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url($link_url); ?>" target="<?php echo esc_attr($link_target); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($link_title); ?></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 position-relative <?= $directionImage; ?> <?= $overImg; ?>">
        <div id="parallax-container" data-speed="0.5">
            <div></div>
            <?php if ($backgroundColourBlock == 'yes') : ?>
                <div id="parallax-bg" class="parallax-item"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div id="middle-image" class="parallax-item"><?= wp_get_attachment_image($imageTwo, 'large'); ?></div>
            <div id="front-image" class="parallax-item"><?= wp_get_attachment_image($imageOne, 'large'); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
if ($bgColour == 'yes') : ?>
</div>

Javascript:
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
let parent =  document.getElementById('parallax-container');
let children = parent.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
children[i].style.transform = 'translateY(calc(200px - ' + (window.scrollY * i / 
children.length) + 'px))';
}
}, false)


Unless you write your own parallax code, it probably wont be worth the effort (for the effect) to hack through the plugin's code to hacky support the behavior you desire for this one instance.

Yeah that is very true, as the amount of time spent on this is already exceeding the budget lol, and you're right i guess the only way really to make this work would be to make an individual block for each instance, which is quite a load of data

Instead of using an ID which constrains you to one per page, switch to something else such as a class or a custom data attribute. Then instead of document.getElementById which only gets you one you can use document.querySelectorAll which get you a collection that you can iterate over. The rest of your code then stays the same.
Below is an example of using a class of parallax-container instead of (just) an ID. You might also need to check your CSS if you have additional things dependent on the ID.
This code hasn't been tested, but I'm fairly certain it should work as presented.
window
    .addEventListener(
        'scroll',
        () => {
            document
                .querySelectorAll('.parallax-container')
                .forEach(
                    (parent) => {
                        let children = parent.getElementsByTagName('div');
                        for(let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                            children[i].style.transform = 'translateY(calc(200px - ' + (window.scrollY * i / children.length) + 'px))';
                        }                        
                    }
                )
            ;
        },
        false
    )
;

